# Why does the program print only the last line of the file, even after reading the entire file?

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I want to write a program in C which just reads a file, stores it into an array and then prints the array. Everything works fine but when the text file has more than one line, I always just get the last line printed out.

This is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   FILE * stream;
   char dateiname[255];
   stream = fopen("heute.txt", "r");

   if(stream == NULL){
      printf("Error");
      }else {
          while(!feof(stream)){
             fgets(dateiname, 255, stream);
      }
    fclose(stream);
    }

printf("%s\n", dateiname);
```

}

Thanks for help!

Comment: You only see the last item because you read all of the data into the same variable. Each line replaces the previous line and when you get to the end you print what's in that buffer.  You can move the `printf` to print each line as it is read. You should also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Or use an actual debugger to step through the code.

Comment: `while(!feof)` is always a bug. Search this site why it is so.

Comment: What is the purpose of your assignment or exercise? Just to copy the contents of the file to the console? To store the data and perform operations on it? Something else? Please [edit] your question to include the full text of your assignment or exercise.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Everything works fine but when the text file has more than one line, I always just get the last line printed out

Reason: For every iteration, the data gets replaced with the next line data, and at the end `dateiname` will read only the last line.

2. > while(!feof(stream))

Usage of `feof()` is not recommended. Please see this link for more information :https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1046476070

3. Please see the following code:

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
      FILE *stream;
      char dateiname[1024];
      int i = 0;
      stream = fopen("heute.txt", "r");

       if (stream == NULL)
       {
          printf("Error");
       }
       else
       {
           while (fgets(dateiname, sizeof(dateiname), stream) != NULL)
           {
              printf("Line %4d: %s", i, dateiname);
              i++;
           } 
       }

    return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just read and print the contents of the file you no need to worry about the size of the file and how many number of lines you have in file.

you can just run `fgets()` in the `while` and print each line until we reach `NULL`

But if you want to store them, we need to calculate the size of the file.
So we need to use functions like `stat` or `fstat` to get the size of the file and allocate memory dynamically then just `read` that many bytes.

Comment: The functions `stat` and `fstat` are not part of the ISO C standard. They are platform-specific extensions. Note that the question does not specify any particular platform. As far as I know, there is no reliable way to determine the file size in ISO C. For example, using `fseek` to go to the end of the file and then using `ftell` will not work reliably on all platforms, because the end of line markers can have a different length on different platforms. For example, Windows uses `\r\n` which is translated to `\n`.